# How to combine 2 arrays in Javascript with headers

Tags: javascript, arrays

So I have 2 arrays:
(from user table)

```
[{
  "id": "123",
  "name": "Peter",
  "description": "person in the office"
}]
```

(from department table)

```
[{
  "id": "R1",
  "name": "Marketing",
  "description": "Yea Marketing"
},
{
  "id": "R2",
  "name": "Sales",
  "description": "More Sales"
}]
```

what I want to do is combine the two arrays into a single array to look like this:

```
[{
  "user": [{
      "id": "123",
      "name": "Peter",
      "description": "person in the office" }],
  "department": [{
      "id": "R1",
      "name": "Marketing",
      "description": "Yea Marketing"
    },
    {
      "id": "R2",
      "name": "Sales",
      "description": "More Sales"
    }]
}]
```

I know how to concat arrays and push but both ways only merge the data together without allowing me to add in the headers of user and department.  If I use concat with strings to add in the headers then I get back [{ "\"user\": [{ \n \"name\":.....

Is there a way I can combine the arrays and add some type of header field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you're after?

```
var user = [{
  "id": "123",
  "name": "Peter",
  "description": "person in the office"
}];

var departments = [{
  "id": "R1",
  "name": "Marketing",
  "description": "Yea Marketing"
},
{
  "id": "R2",
  "name": "Sales",
  "description": "More Sales"
}];

var combined = [{
    user: user,
    department: departments,
}];
```

Comment: Yep that was it.  I did not think about making them variables.  Thanks for helping me out.

Answer (score 1):

```
var userArr = [{
  "id": "123",
  "name": "Peter",
  "description": "person in the office"
}];
var deptArr = [{
  "id": "R1",
  "name": "Marketing",
  "description": "Yea Marketing"
},
{
  "id": "R2",
  "name": "Sales",
  "description": "More Sales"
}];

var merged = [];
merged.push({'user':userArr,'department':deptArr});
```

Comment: This also worked.  I might use this for a different solution.  Thanks.